# 指定の時刻になったらDebianを強制的にシャットダウンするOSSを作りたい

Tags: javascript, debian, oss

こんばんは。お世話になります。

私は発達障害持ちです。発達障害の症状で興味のあることに対しては集中しすぎる症状（過集中と呼びます）があります。12時間以上水もろくに飲まずトイレにもほとんど行かずに集中しすぎてしまいます。

また、Debianに夢中になりすぎるあまり、お風呂にも何日も入れなくなってしまいます。夜も眠れなくなってしまいます。

それを防ぐために、Debianを強制シャットダウンするOSSを作りたいです。
今所属しているスタートアップではJavaScriptを覚えるように言われておりますので、JavaScriptでできたら作りたいのですが、、

機能は、安全にシャットダウンするために5分だけ延長する機能と、
シャットダウンまであとX分とかをGUIに表示する機能がほしいです。

また、緊急時のために、夜中1時にシャットダウンしたら5分後には再起動できるようにしたいです。

どの言語でどのフレームワークで作ればよいのでしょうか。ご教授願ます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript言語でDebian上でGUIが使えてシェルコマンドを発行できるとなると
有名なフレームワークにElectronがあります。
https://electronjs.org/

私も過集中するときがあるので分かります。
しかし仕組みをうまく考えないと人間の意志との勝負なのでなかなか難しいと思います。
がんばってください。

Comment: 様　パソコンが壊れておりました、遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。Electronという手もあるのですね！教えていただきありがとうございます。過集中をシャットダウンする仕組みって大事ですよね。頑張ります！